# Binding doesn't work in nested elements inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this code:

```
<div class="list-group">
<a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{user.FirstName}} {{user.FirstName}}</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">
        <a href="#">{{user.Phone}}</a>
    </p>
</a>
```

If I use {{user.Phone}} not inside the `<a>` it works, otherwise it displays nothing and I don't get any error or anything.

Comment: make fiddle for this or paste your controller code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put an `<a>` tag within an `<a>` tag. This is against HTML definition.

Try changing your outer `<a>` tag to a `<div>` and remove the href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you have an html error there: a link inside a link. Notice that the user.Phone link is inside the already existing link that you use ng-repeat on:

I would change code to this:

```
<div href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{user.FirstName}} {{user.FirstName}}</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text"><a href="#">{{user.Phone}}</a></p>
</div>
```